# "exec format error" error running Docker container

Tags: docker, tensorflow, ubuntu

I'm not able to run the docker container which I created.

I am using this command For manylinux2010

```
docker pull tensorflow/tensorflow:custom-op-gpu-ubuntu16
```

For GPU, use nvidia-docker

```
docker run --runtime=nvidia --privileged -it -v ${PWD}:/working_dir -w /working_dir tensorflow/tensorflow:custom-op-gpu-ubuntu16
```

I got this error

standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "exec format error"

I want to build pip inside the docker container.This is the link https://github.com/tensorflow/custom-op

If anyone can help ?

Comment: What are you trying to run this on? "exec format error" usually means you're trying to run an image built for one cpu arch like x64 on a different cpu arch like Raspberry Pi ARM. The image you're trying to run needs to be built for the target cpu architecture

Comment: I am using ppc64le arch of IBM and gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0. I want to build pip inside the tensorflow compression docker container.

Comment: Is the image you are attempting to run on ppc built for ppc? If not, this is the issue. You can't run an x64 arch image on ppc or vice versa

Comment: Thank you for reply but I am not sure its built for ppc or not. I am using the image from here https://github.com/tensorflow/custom-op.

Comment: If you're following the instructions on the site, then it's not. Docker image tensorflow/tensorflow:custom-op-ubuntu14 is built for amd64 not ppc. See os/arch listed here https://hub.docker.com/layers/tensorflow/tensorflow/custom-op-gpu-ubuntu14/images/sha256-ef019e4f844256731cb5595ecb50c65a5f500f6982f5881dcc9e6cc73ec47bad